# How are Methods with different modifiers called exactly

Tags: c#, methods, console-application, call, access-modifiers

this is my first post. I am trying to run this C# code I am getting an undesired output:

**When I run the following code**:

```
class Car1
    {
        public void PublicHelperMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Public helper method");
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod());
        }

        private string PrivateHelperMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Private Helper Method Called!");
            return "Now Inside Private Helper method";
        }
    }
```

**I am expecting the output to be in this order**:

> Inside Public helper method
>
> Calling Private Helper method..Private Helper Method Called!
>
> Now Inside Private Helper method

**But I am getting the following output**:

> Inside Public helper method
>
> Private Helper Method Called!
>
> Calling Private Helper method..Now Inside Private Helper method

What am I missing? Why did the order change?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are passing to `Console.WriteLine()` the string formed by the expression `"Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod()`. How could it _possibly_ evaluate that expression, never mind call the method, before it had finished calling `PrivateHelperMethod()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all because of the way in which C# evaluates expressions.

Let's do this method call by method call.

```
Console.WriteLine("Inside Public helper method");
```

Nice and easy, prints `Inside Public helper method`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod());
```

Here, C# sees that you want to print something. But the thing that you want to print is `"Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod()`. This means that it must know the return value of `PrivateHelperMethod` first before printing. To know the return value, the method has to be called. Inside `PrivateHelperMethod`, we have

```
Console.WriteLine("Private Helper Method Called!");
```

Again, a simple one. Just prints `Private Helper Method Called!`.

Then `PrivateHelperMethod` returns a value. The value is appended to `Calling Private Helper method..`. Now the whole thing that you want to print has been fully evaluated, it prints `Calling Private Helper method..Now Inside Private Helper method`.

> what do I do to get the desired output without having two Console.WriteLine statements?

```
class Car1
{
    public void PublicHelperMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Public helper method");
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod());
    }

    private string PrivateHelperMethod()
    {
        return "Private Helper Method Called!\nNow Inside Private Helper method";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the the whole of PrivateHelperMethod() needs to be evaluated first, Why isn't it this the output then:


Inside Public Helper Method

Private Helper Method Called!

Now inside Private helper method

Calling Private Helper method

Comment: @SivaramaKrishnan because the `PrivateHelperMethod` does not print anything to the console. It just returns the value which is then added to **"Calling Private Helper method.."** and then printed to the console

Comment: Clarifies! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line `Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod());` which is for printing something in the console right? and the value to be printed will be a concatenated string right? So before printing that it will check for the second string to perform the concatenation, and that moves the control to the `PrivateHelperMethod` so the `Private Helper Method Called!` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because before your second `WriteLine` in `PublicHelperMethod` is executed, your `PrivateHelperMethod` runs.

What you can do instead is:

```
class Car1
{
    public void PublicHelperMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Public helper method");
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method..");
        Console.WriteLine(PrivateHelperMethod());        
    }

    private string PrivateHelperMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Private Helper Method Called!");
        return "Now Inside Private Helper method";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, he probably edited his post then. Because when I posted my answer, there were 2 answers which had `0 lines of code` but just plain text, which I believe should be a comment, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

```
public void PublicHelperMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Public helper method");
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Private Helper method.." + PrivateHelperMethod());
        Console.WriteLine("Private Helper Method Called!");
    }

    private string PrivateHelperMethod()
    {
        return "Now Inside Private Helper method";
    }
```

You write "Private Method Called" when it called and the job is done.